# cannot get dynamic added custom select to work in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have looked through all of the similar questions available at the time of this question, and none of the solutions presented worked in the below code. Google was also not helpful except that I did find a few issues with dynamic code where the entire menu was not wrapped, but those issues should be fixed with either the trigger or enhanceWithin methods - which have been tried here.

I am a fairly new with javascript and the jquery library and this is my first app with jquery mobile.

The raw html as generated from the php file:

```
<div class="cell_container force_org_select">
<label for"force_org[new_555]" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Troop Type</label>
<select name="force_org[new_555]" id="force_org[new_555]" class="roster_cell" data-mini="true">
<option value="hq">HQ</option>
<option value="elite">Elite</option>
<option value="solo">Solitaire</option>
<option value="formation">Std Formation</option>
</select>
```

The Javascript function that handles the dynamic injection:

```
    $(document).on('click','.add_item', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var the_link = $(this).attr('href')
    var area = getParameterByName(the_link, 'area');
    var type = getParameterByName(the_link, 'type');
    var squad_id = getParameterByName(the_link, 'squad_id');
    var vehicle = getParameterByName(the_link, 'vehicle');
    var divider = getParameterByName(the_link, 'divider');
    var preset = $('#preset').val();

    $.post(cmd_ajax.ajaxurl,{action: 'cmd_add_item_mobile', type: type, preset: preset, squad_id: squad_id, vehicle: vehicle, divider: divider}, function(data) {
        if(type == 'squad' || type == 'divider') {
            $('#list').append(data).enhanceWithin();
            //$('#list').append(data).trigger("refresh");
            //$('#list').append(data).trigger("create");

            $('.squad_help_button').tooltipster({
                contentCloning: true,
                trigger: 'custom',
                triggerOpen: {
                    click: true,
                    tap: true
                },
                triggerClose: {
                    click: true,
                    tap: true
                }
            });

        }
        else {
            $('#' + area).append(data).enhanceWithin();
        }
        //console.log("squad_id:"+this_id);

        set_unit_sortable();
    });

    return false;
});
```

I also tried adding the `.selectmenu("refresh",true)` within the function and that seems to do nothing. The custom selects that are not dynamically generated work fine.

If I use the `data-native-menu="false"` attribute on the generated select menus, the popup does not function and you cannot select anything, if I remove the attribute, the native select works as it should.

I thought about using a selectmenu() refresh at the very end of the function, but I can't seem to catch the element id of the select menu either. My only guess is that it isn't created yet in the DOM when I try to retrieve it.